# Puppeteer failed to launch browser process in GoormIDE

Tags: node.js, ide, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

async function scrapeA (url) {
    return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            **const browser = await puppeteer.launch();**

            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(url)
            page.$eval('#city', elem => elem.click());

            const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[2]/h1/a');
            const txt1 = await el.getProperty('innerText');
            const nameA =  await txt1.jsonValue();

            const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="offerPrice_328504"]');
            const txt2 = await el2.getProperty('innerText');
            const priceA =  await txt2.jsonValue();

            const [el3] = await page.$x('//*[@id="inventoryTableBody"]/div[5]/div[3]/span[1]');
            const txt3 = await el3.getProperty('innerText');
            const quantA =  await txt3.jsonValue();

            const [el4] = await page.$x('//*//*[@id="inventoryTableBody"]/div[5]/div[2]/text()[1]');
            const txt4 = await el4.getProperty('textContent');
            const locA =  await txt4.jsonValue();

            console.log({nameA},{priceA},{quantA},{locA});

            browser.close();
            return resolve();
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }    
    })
}
scrapeA(webpageurl);
```

This code works in my code editor.  I am trying to get some back-end to this, so I moved it into  my GoormIDE.  The browser process fails to launch

I have tried all combinations of 2 different packages: puppeteer and puppeteer-core

and 3 different launch settings:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false}); 
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']});
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing packages using

```sh
apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget libgbm-dev
```

And try this

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
```

Comment: 1. I need to install 408MB of packages??   2. Developers.google strongly advises against no sandboxing for security reasons.

Comment: GoormIde is of course an Ide I use from a browser.   Is the headless browsing function of puppeteer inherently stymied here?

Comment: 1. Most packages are already installed. Only some of them will be installed.
2. Because the goormide operates inside the docker container, it is not necessary to consider security for root user. If you are concerned, you can turn off the no sandboxing option and run it under a non-root user.

Comment: Goormide is used in a browser but its interior is not a browser.
Think of it as using ubuntu.